# Насколько плохо из шаблона (представления) при событии обращаться напрямую к сервису?

Tags: javascript, angular

Насколько плохо из шаблона (представления) при событии обращаться напрямую к сервису (например при onclick или какой-то другой метод, о котором я не знаю, но если вы знаете подскажите)? Или лучше делать это обращение через компонент?

Comment: что вам мешает это делать из шаблона? вот эта часть вопроса `например при onclick или какой-то другой метод, о котором я не знаю, но если вы знаете подскажите` - что подсказать?

Answer (score -1):

Вариант с шаблоном допустим. Только сервис в конструкторе надо объявить как public

`constructor(
  public myService: MyService,
) {}`